# Separar una cadena de notas de piano

Tags: javascript

Buenas tengo un problema, necesito separar una cadena de texto
que de el usuario ejemplo:

```
let cadena = prompt("Dame las notas musicales"); // "C6F#6A5"

resultado en consola:
C6
F#6
A5
el total de de notas de piano es 3
```

Pd: no se necesita comprobar si existe esa nota de piano solo seguir la siguientes estructura:
Letra + Numero O Letra + Signo(#) + Numero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más simple y optima a mi parecer sería utilizar una expresión regular.
algo así podría funcionar.

Si quieres que solamente tenga en cuenta las notas que tienen letras mayúsculas, quita la i al final de musicNotesRegex

```js
const musicNotesRegex =  /([A-Z][0-9])|([A-Z]#[0-9])/gi;
const text = "C6F#6A5";
console.log(text.match(musicNotesRegex));
```

#### Para el resultado que buscas tal cual necesitarías lo siguiente.

```js
const musicNotesRegex = /([A-Z][0-9])|([A-Z]#[0-9])/gi;
const userText        = prompt("Ingresa las notas de piano");
const musicNotes      = userText.match(musicNotesRegex);
const musicNotesText  = musicNotes.toString().replaceAll(",", "\n");

console.log(`${musicNotesText}
  El total de notas de piano es ${musicNotes.length}
`)
```

Answer (score 0):

no se si es la mejor forma de resolverlo, pero cumple con lo que quiero:

```
let cadena = "D#2G#3C3C4G4";  //"C6F#6A5";
let nota;
let notas = [];

for(let i=0; i < cadena.length ; i++){
    if(isNaN(cadena[i]) && typeof parseInt(cadena[i+1]) === 'number' && cadena[i] != "#" && cadena[i+1] != "#" ){
        nota = cadena[i];
        nota = nota + cadena[i+1];
        notas.push(nota);
        nota = ""; 
    }
    else{
        if(isNaN(cadena[i]) && cadena[i+1] == "#" && typeof parseInt(cadena[i+2]) === 'number'){
            nota = cadena[i];
            nota = nota + cadena[i+1];
            nota = nota + cadena[i+2];
            notas.push(nota);
            nota = "";
        }
    }
}

console.log(notas)
console.log(notas.length)
```

```
['D#2', 'G#3', 'C3', 'C4', 'G4']
5
```